# python vs matlab?

Tags: matlab, python

What is so special about MATLAB? Why in engineering (especially electrical engineering) hasn't pyhton replaced it?

I was watching a Youtube video regarding MATLAB:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7f50sQYjNRA&list=PPSV&ab_channel=freeCodeCamp.org

In video description it is written:

> "MATLAB is a programming language and software suite used for data
> analysis, scientific computing, and visualization that is widely used
> in academia and industry."

Also in Google search I found out another important use, that MATLAB is especially useful for numeric computing.

I wonder, can't we perform all the above mentioned activities using python?

Comment: Sure you can use Python or any other language to do whatever you want. Some tasks are easy in some languages and some other tasks are easy in some other languages. Sometimes you use a tool because you already know it because you have learnt it already (maybe during studies), so why take a slower route and use another tool where you need to re-learn how to do the same thing you already can with another tool. There is no generic answer.

Comment: MATLAB was there when use if computers and numerical solutions became practical in engineering. Thats why. Now I see many more students being already somewhat adept with numpy/scipy than MATLAB, so it is not hard to predict where things are heading

Comment: Matlab toolboxes and Simulink are more than just a language. They also use academic institutional licensing very effectively to promote their (rather expensive) product. As open-source alternatives improve they should take more market share.

Answer (score 0):

Matlab is an ecosystem specifically built around math and fields that utilize math. It has its own IDE, and a very large standard library (Again, built around math and engineering). Because of Matlab's high price, it has extensive documentation *and* support. Since Matlab is now a staple in the engineering fields, it can be simple to transfer solutions and knowledge to other engineers.

All this being said, Python could very much replace Matlab in the long run, but it would take a while to displace all of the current Matlab usage out there in the field.

Sources:
https://pyzo.org/python_vs_matlab.html
https://www.eeweb.com/python-vs-matlab-for-electrical-engineers/

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge, there are a few points why MATLAB has not (yet) been replaced. The list might not be exhaustive, but in short:

- Its feature set is very specifically optimized for an engineering and data analysis workflow. Python and other languages can do the same job, but might require more coding or specific libraries. Python might be able to keep up in terms of visualization, maybe even numerical optimization. But what about e.g. filter synthesis?
- It is easy to integrate with both physical setups and other simulation software - Simulink is the first thing that comes to mind, but it does not end there. Pretty much every major design suite has a MATLAB interface.
- With so many companies using MATLAB, and so many universities teaching it, being fluent in MATLAB has become a significant skill for many job applicants. The companies, on the other hand, can't afford to re-train all their employees in another language/software.
- Bort also pointed out documentation and support. This is something we often forget (as did I) as individuals, but at company scale, paying for support contracts is actually worth the money - imagine your employees having to fix bugs in some poorly documented python package.

Widespread Python use has only become a thing recently, at least in my perception. Also, comparing the development history of Python and MATLAB, MATLAB has been around for 20-30 years longer.

That being said, Python (or another language) might take over one day. For example, the more maths/statistics-heavy institute of communications engineering at my university is already using mostly Python, Meanwhile, CSE (control systems engineering) relies heavily upon MATLAB.